# Herokuにマスターデータファイルを上げたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Railsアプリケーションでdb:seedする際にgitで管理していないymlファイル(これはgithubで公開したくないファイル。ここではmaster_data.ymlとします)を用いてDBにデータを入れています。
そして、このアプリケーションをHerokuにデプロイする際にmaster_data.ymlがないためにdb:seedするとエラーが出てDBにデータを入れられません。

この場合、どのようにしてmaster_data.ymlをHeroku上に上げるのが良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3など外部にyamlファイルを置いてそれを読み込む方法と、ローカルのDBからHerokuにデータを送り込む方法がありそうです。

外部からデータを読み込む場合はseed.rbのコードを変更する必要があります。

```
require 'open-uri'

url = '(yamlファイルのURL)'
yaml = YAML.load(open(url).read)
```

ローカルDB（Postgresであることが前提）のデータをHerokuに送り込む場合は、以下のような手順になります。

```
# ローカルのデータをダンプ
$ pg_dump --verbose --clean --no-owner --no-acl --format=c (アプリ名)_development > db.dump

# Heroku上のDBに対してリストア（passwordは実行時に入力を要求される）
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h (host) -U (username) -d (dbname) db.dump
```

Heroku DBのhost, username, dbname, passwordはそれぞれ「Herokuの管理画面 => Add-onsのHeroku::Postgressをクリック」で表示されます。（下図のような画面）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

DBのダンプ＆リストアなので、当然開発環境の全データがそのままコピーされます。
必要に応じてリストア後にデータを整理してください。

マスタデータに複雑な関連がないのであれば、CSVから取り込むことも可能です。

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/users.csv
Alice,alice@example.com
Bob,bob@example.com

$ psql `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL --app (Heroku上のアプリ名)` -c "\copy users(name, email) from '~/Desktop/users.csv' ( delimiter E',', format csv, header false )"
```

お好みの方法を試してみてください。

Comment: ローカルDBのデータをHerokuに送り込む方法で対応しました。
助かりました！
ありがとうございます:-)

Comment: うまく対応できたようでよかったです！あと、[こちらのページ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参考にして回答の承認もお願いします。他のユーザーさんがこのページを見たときに、解決済みだということがすぐにわかるので。よろしくお願いします！